# How to turn a Vega chart's legend into vertical

Tags: d3.js, charts, visualization, vega

I want to turn the legend of [this heatmap](http://vega.github.io/vega-editor/?mode=vega&spec=heatmap) from being horizontal to vertical, so much less space is wasted.

I have reviewed [the documentation](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Legends) but there is no option to do that, just to move it from being left, to right using the "orient" property.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see [an option for it](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Legends) in there API.  Are you using the SVG renderer? If so, you could manipulate it after the draw.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to answer as I don't know how to select a renderer or what does it allow me to do.